# How are Yonex and Victor feathered shuttlecocks comparable?

Tags: equipment, badminton

The Yonex:

1. AC TR
2. AS 10
3. AS 20
4. AS 30
5. AS 40
6. AS 50

and Victor

1. Pro Court
2. Queen
3. Special
4. Maxima
5. Service
6. Champion
7. Master ACE

How are these shuttlecocks comparable?

Comment: Clarifying the reason as to why you are interested in these comparisons will help us better help you. For example, are you looking for specifications or prices? If you are looking for prices, then this is [off-topic](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) throughout the series of Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Why should I compare the prices if I do not know the shuttlecocks properties and target group? It is absolutely obvious that first one need to get specifications or real experience meaning using in practice, then eventually look in to the prices.

Comment: You're getting close votes...and I'm defending you. It wasn't "absolutely obvious" enough to two users to give this question a close vote, so I suggested clarification. I play golf, and golf balls have many different properties to consider wrt playing the sport (feel, control, distance, quality, etc) before price...and I figured shuttlecocks were the same. Again, it was "pretty clear" to at least one user (and that's a quote) that this was a shopping recommendation, but it isn't clear either way (price, specs, etc) based on "here are these shuttlecocks, are they comparable"? in which ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From personal experience, manufacturers seem to be able to sort their best and worst shuttles. Since manufacturing processes are reasonably similar, Victor Master ACE will usually fly better than YONEX AS 10.

Shuttles are tested by the BWF for international events and national/regional associations for their events. As you can see in the [BWF guidelines](http://www.bwfbadminton.org/file.aspx?id=473031&dl=1) these tests focus on shuttle speed and construction, not durability (some national and regional associations may report those too).

The BWF maintains a [list of approved shuttles](http://www.bwfbadminton.org/page.aspx?id=14913), which includes Victor Master Ace, YONEX AS 40, and YONEX AS 50. All of these shuttles are used in international tournaments and therefore of high quality.

In summary, you can expect roughly similar qualities, but with widely varying details. For example, within the batches I've tested, AS40 certainly beat Master ACE.

Comment: Club players as me, usually use Yonex AS 30 or RSL Classic Tourney, at least in my country. By using simple logic one can assume that AC TR and Pro Court are almost the same quality. It was very helpful to me to know that Master ACE is not as good as AS 40 and AS 50. I wonder if Service is as good as AS 30 or RSL Classic Tourney. Thank you for your answer.